# Issue using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add data to a pandas dataframe. I am having isses getting to the sub directories. Ideally i would like all of the ratio names like "priceBookValueRatio", "priceToBookRatio", ...ect in the first column, with the dates on the top row going left to right, and the appropriate values under each date. Can anyone help?

Here is my code

```
def get_jsonparsed_data(ticker):
    url = ("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financial-ratios/" + ticker)
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    value = json.loads(data)
    data = value["ratios"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print df
```

And here is what my data looks like

```
{

"symbol" : "AAPL",

"ratios" : [ {
    "date" : "2019-09-28",
    "investmentValuationRatios" : {
      "priceBookValueRatio" : "11.1154",
      "priceToBookRatio" : "11.1154",
      "priceToSalesRatio" : "3.8903",
      "priceEarningsRatio" : "18.7109",
      "receivablesTurnover" : "5.489",
      "priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio" : "17.5607",
      "priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio" : "14.5863",
      "priceCashFlowRatio" : "0",
      "priceEarningsToGrowthRatio" : "0",
      "priceSalesRatio" : "0",
      "dividendYield" : "",
      "enterpriseValueMultiple" : "1.7966762045884",
      "priceFairValue" : "0"
    },
    "profitabilityIndicatorRatios" : {
      "niperEBT" : "0.84056163195765",
      "ebtperEBIT" : "1",
      "ebitperRevenue" : "0.25266552384174",
      "grossProfitMargin" : "0.37817768109035",
      "operatingProfitMargin" : "1",
      "pretaxProfitMargin" : "0.24572017188497",
      "netProfitMargin" : "0.21238094505984",
      "effectiveTaxRate" : "0.15943836804235",
      "returnOnAssets" : "0.5848",
      "returnOnEquity" : "0.6106",
      "returnOnCapitalEmployed" : "0.2691",
      "nIperEBT" : "0.84056163195765",
      "eBTperEBIT" : "1",
      "eBITperRevenue" : "0.25266552384174"
    },
    "operatingPerformanceRatios" : {
      "receivablesTurnover" : "5.489",
      "payablesTurnover" : "1.2542",
      "inventoryTurnover" : "64.5433",
      "fixedAssetTurnover" : "6.9606185456686",
      "assetTurnover" : "0.76857223883066"
    },
    "liquidityMeasurementRatios" : {
      "currentRatio" : "1.54",
      "quickRatio" : "1.3844473032029",
      "cashRatio" : "0.46202160464632",
      "daysOfSalesOutstanding" : "-9.2636",
      "daysOfInventoryOutstanding" : "64.2588",
      "operatingCycle" : "",
      "daysOfPayablesOutstanding" : "64.8648",
      "cashConversionCycle" : ""
    },
    "debtRatios" : {
      "debtRatio" : "0.3192",
      "debtEquityRatio" : "1.194",
      "longtermDebtToCapitalization" : "0.50361776241806",
      "totalDebtToCapitalization" : "0.54422142191553",
      "interestCoverage" : "0.0",
      "cashFlowToDebtRatio" : "0.64222977037771",
      "companyEquityMultiplier" : "3.7410043320661"
    },
    "cashFlowIndicatorRatios" : {
      "operatingCashFlowPerShare" : "15.0267",
      "freeCashFlowPerShare" : "12.94",
      "cashPerShare" : "10.5773",
      "payoutRatio" : "0.251",
      "receivablesTurnover" : "5.489",
      "operatingCashFlowSalesRatio" : "0.26670997101939",
      "freeCashFlowOperatingCashFlowRatio" : "0.84875560231154",
      "cashFlowCoverageRatios" : "0.64222977037771",
      "shortTermCoverageRatios" : "4.2728448275862",
      "capitalExpenditureCoverageRatios" : "6.6118151500715",
      "dividendpaidAndCapexCoverageRatios" : "2.8191679531974",
      "dividendPayoutRatio" : "0.25551976255972"
    }
  }, 


{
    "date" : "2018-09-29",
    "investmentValuationRatios" : {
      "priceBookValueRatio" : "10.1842",
      "priceToBookRatio" : "10.1842",
      "priceToSalesRatio" : "4.1328",
      "priceEarningsRatio" : "18.9226",
      "receivablesTurnover" : "6.2738",
      "priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio" : "17.563",
      "priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio" : "14.1753",
      "priceCashFlowRatio" : "14.375642493446",
      "priceEarningsToGrowthRatio" : "18.698887988401",
      "priceSalesRatio" : "4.1912065394209",
      "dividendYield" : "0.012318046710734",
      "enterpriseValueMultiple" : "14.710301181747",
      "priceFairValue" : "10.389124295011"
    },
    "profitabilityIndicatorRatios" : {
      "niperEBT" : "0.81657819294131",
      "ebtperEBIT" : "1",
      "ebitperRevenue" : "0.27448935409176",
      "grossProfitMargin" : "0.38343718820008",
      "operatingProfitMargin" : "1",
      "pretaxProfitMargin" : "0.26694026619477",
      "netProfitMargin" : "0.22414202074587",
      "effectiveTaxRate" : "0.18342180705869",
      "returnOnAssets" : "1.0497",
      "returnOnEquity" : "0.5556",
      "returnOnCapitalEmployed" : "0.217",
      "nIperEBT" : "0.81657819294131",
      "eBTperEBIT" : "1",
      "eBITperRevenue" : "0.27448935409176"
    },
    "operatingPerformanceRatios" : {
      "receivablesTurnover" : "6.2738",
      "payablesTurnover" : "1.2564",
      "inventoryTurnover" : "60.2871",
      "fixedAssetTurnover" : "6.4302488863064",
      "assetTurnover" : "0.72621505229339"
    },
    "liquidityMeasurementRatios" : {
      "currentRatio" : "1.133",
      "quickRatio" : "0.99453976140569",
      "cashRatio" : "0.22352474359306",
      "daysOfSalesOutstanding" : "-8.8176",
      "daysOfInventoryOutstanding" : "67.3325",
      "operatingCycle" : "",
      "daysOfPayablesOutstanding" : "76.8054",
      "cashConversionCycle" : ""
    },
    "debtRatios" : {
      "debtRatio" : "0.313",
      "debtEquityRatio" : "1.0685",
      "longtermDebtToCapitalization" : "0.46661721806832",
      "totalDebtToCapitalization" : "0.51655010603258",
      "interestCoverage" : "0.0",
      "cashFlowToDebtRatio" : "0.67637989919901",
      "companyEquityMultiplier" : "3.4133013523477"
    },
    "cashFlowIndicatorRatios" : {
      "operatingCashFlowPerShare" : "15.6263",
      "freeCashFlowPerShare" : "9.924",
      "cashPerShare" : "5.2293",
      "payoutRatio" : "0.226",
      "receivablesTurnover" : "6.2738",
      "operatingCashFlowSalesRatio" : "0.29154916319961",
      "freeCashFlowOperatingCashFlowRatio" : "0.8280729395356",
      "cashFlowCoverageRatios" : "0.67637989919901",
      "shortTermCoverageRatios" : "3.7321187584345",
      "capitalExpenditureCoverageRatios" : "5.8164200405619",
      "dividendpaidAndCapexCoverageRatios" : "2.8652728954672",
      "dividendPayoutRatio" : "0.2303337756799"
    }
  }, 

{
    "date" : "2017-09-30",
    "investmentValuationRatios" : {
      "priceBookValueRatio" : "5.9086",
      "priceToBookRatio" : "5.9086",
      "priceToSalesRatio" : "3.4657",
      "priceEarningsRatio" : "16.5922",
      "receivablesTurnover" : "7.0564",
      "priceToFreeCashFlowsRatio" : "15.4994",
      "priceToOperatingCashFlowsRatio" : "12.37",
      "priceCashFlowRatio" : "12.166429629599",
      "priceEarningsToGrowthRatio" : "16.160760748713",
      "priceSalesRatio" : "3.4086956688842",
      "dividendYield" : "0.016341413728755",
      "enterpriseValueMultiple" : "12.106846738693",
      "priceFairValue" : "5.8292161925369"
    },
    "profitabilityIndicatorRatios" : {
      "niperEBT" : "0.75443523849647",
      "ebtperEBIT" : "1",
      "ebitperRevenue" : "0.27957894553164",
      "grossProfitMargin" : "0.38469860491899",
      "operatingProfitMargin" : "1",
      "pretaxProfitMargin" : "0.2676042820873",
      "netProfitMargin" : "0.21092420845075",
      "effectiveTaxRate" : "0.24556476150353",
      "returnOnAssets" : "0.7847",
      "returnOnEquity" : "0.3607",
      "returnOnCapitalEmployed" : "0.1752",
      "nIperEBT" : "0.75443523849647",
      "eBTperEBIT" : "1",
      "eBITperRevenue" : "0.27957894553164"
    },
    "operatingPerformanceRatios" : {
      "receivablesTurnover" : "7.0564",
      "payablesTurnover" : "1.2897",
      "inventoryTurnover" : "65.6173",
      "fixedAssetTurnover" : "6.7854838232247",
      "assetTurnover" : "0.61077110404749"
    },
    "liquidityMeasurementRatios" : {
      "currentRatio" : "1.276",
      "quickRatio" : "1.089670085504",
      "cashRatio" : "0.20125181026445",
      "daysOfSalesOutstanding" : "-12.5636",
      "daysOfInventoryOutstanding" : "56.8007",
      "operatingCycle" : "",
      "daysOfPayablesOutstanding" : "70.4447",
      "cashConversionCycle" : ""
    },
    "debtRatios" : {
      "debtRatio" : "0.3082",
      "debtEquityRatio" : "0.863",
      "longtermDebtToCapitalization" : "0.42034732372197",
      "totalDebtToCapitalization" : "0.46322584262014",
      "interestCoverage" : "0.0",
      "cashFlowToDebtRatio" : "0.55519536652835",
      "companyEquityMultiplier" : "2.7999060031183"
    },
    "cashFlowIndicatorRatios" : {
      "operatingCashFlowPerShare" : "12.3101",
      "freeCashFlowPerShare" : "9.779",
      "cashPerShare" : "3.8888",
      "payoutRatio" : "0.259",
      "receivablesTurnover" : "7.0564",
      "operatingCashFlowSalesRatio" : "0.28017222576058",
      "freeCashFlowOperatingCashFlowRatio" : "0.80613468275594",
      "cashFlowCoverageRatios" : "0.55519536652835",
      "shortTermCoverageRatios" : "3.476695718075",
      "capitalExpenditureCoverageRatios" : "5.1582202232752",
      "dividendpaidAndCapexCoverageRatios" : "2.5465900079302",
      "dividendPayoutRatio" : "0.26408967756613"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` cant construct a `DataFrame` from an arbitrary nested dict. You need to pass the data through in a standard format it can parse.

One way to do this is to create a list of single level dicts with keys and values and then construct the `DataFrame` from this

```
def clean_data(d):
    ret = {}
    ret['date'] = d['date']
    for outer_key, rec in d.items():
        if outer_key != 'date':
            for k,v in rec.items():
                ret[k]= v
    return ret

cleaned_data = [clean_data(d) for d in data['ratios']]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cleaned_data, index='date')

df = df.transpose()
```

will give you

[image: This df.head()]

Comment: note: We could have used `d.pop('date')` to get the date and not had to check that `outer_key!='date'` but this would have mutated the original data which I wanted to avoid incase it's used later

Comment: Clutch. Thanks. Worked like a charm

Comment: If i wanted to flip the order of this from "newest to oldest" to "oldest to newest" how would i go about that? I tried df = df.columns[::-1] with no luck

Comment: You can use `df = df.reindex(columns=SPECIFIED_COL_ORDER)` see [here]( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)